# GUI Extension not picking up js files

Tags: web8, cme, gui-extensions

I'm trying to add a new column to the GUI (I'm using Web8) which shows the schema name.
I'm following [this](http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com/2012/04/sdl-tridion-2011-data-extenders-real.html) article which specifies that we should take care of refreshing/reloading of a component so we see the name when we first load the screen and later when we open up a component/page/etc (if not the value becomes empty in the column). So far I see the new column with a value but the reload part is not working. When I open (checkout automatically) a component the value in the grid is lost. In developer tools of Chrome there are no errors and in IE it says that **"Unable to upgrade to type "GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedComponent"**. So my guess is that it's not picking up my js files where that constructor is defined.

**DataExtender.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
﻿
<Configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge"
               xmlns:cfg="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration"
                             xmlns:ext="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions"
               xmlns:cmenu="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu">

  <resources cache="true">
    <cfg:filters />
    <cfg:groups>
      <cfg:group name="GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.Model"
     merger="Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Configuration.Resources.DomainModelProcessor"
     merge="always">
        <cfg:domainmodel name="GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.Model">
          <cfg:fileset>
            <cfg:file type="script">/Scripts/ExtendedPage.js</cfg:file>
            <cfg:file type="script">/Scripts/ExtendedComponent.js</cfg:file>
          </cfg:fileset>
          <cfg:services />
        </cfg:domainmodel>
      </cfg:group>
      <cfg:dependencies>
        <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</cfg:dependency>
        <cfg:dependency>GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.Model</cfg:dependency>
      </cfg:dependencies>
    </cfg:groups>
  </resources>
  <definitionfiles />
  <extensions>
    <ext:modelextensions>
      <cfg:itemtypes>
        <cfg:itemtype id="tcm:16" implementation="GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedComponent" />
        <cfg:itemtype id="tcm:64" implementation="GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedPage" />
      </cfg:itemtypes>
    </ext:modelextensions>
    <ext:dataextenders>
      <ext:dataextender type="GUIExtension.GUIDataExtender, GUIDataExtender" name="SchemaNamExtender">
        <ext:description>Schema Name Extender</ext:description>
      </ext:dataextender>
    </ext:dataextenders>
    <ext:editorextensions>
      <ext:editorextension target="CME">
        <ext:editurls/>
        <ext:listdefinitions/>
        <ext:taskbars/>
        <ext:commands/>
        <ext:commandextensions/>
        <ext:contextmenus/>
        <ext:lists>
          <ext:add>
            <ext:extension name="SchemaNameExtender" assignid="SchemaNameExtender" insertbefore="FromPub">
              <ext:listDefinition>
                <ext:selectornamespaces/>
                <ext:columns>
                  <column xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/List"
                              id="SchemaName" type="data" title="Schema Name"
                              selector="@ExtendedInfo" translate="String" />
                </ext:columns>
              </ext:listDefinition>
              <ext:apply>
                <ext:view name="DashboardView" />
              </ext:apply>
            </ext:extension>
          </ext:add>
        </ext:lists>
        <ext:tabpages/>
        <ext:toolbars/>
        <ext:ribbontoolbars/>
      </ext:editorextension>
    </ext:editorextensions>
  </extensions>
  <commands/>
  <contextmenus />
  <localization />
  <settings>
    <defaultpage/>
    <!-- /Views/Default.aspx</defaultpage> -->
    <navigatorurl/>
    <!-- /Views/Default.aspx</navigatorurl> -->
    <editurls/>
    <listdefinitions />
    <itemicons/>
    <theme>
      <path>theme/</path>
    </theme>
    <customconfiguration />
  </settings>
</Configuration>
```

**ExtendedComponent.js**

```
Type.registerNamespace("GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI");

GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedComponent = function ExtendedComponent(id) {
    Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedComponent");
    // test if initiative (from OME) exists
    var isInitiative = false;
    if (Tridion.OO.implementsInterface(this, "Tridion.OnlineMarketing.UI.InitiativeComponent")) {
        this.addInterface("Tridion.OnlineMarketing.UI.InitiativeComponent", [id]);
        isInitiative = true;
    } else {
        this.addInterface("Tridion.ContentManager.Component", [id]);
    }
    var p = this.properties;
    p.isInitiative = isInitiative;
    p.extendedInfo = undefined;
};

GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedComponent.prototype.setDataFromList = function ExtendedComponent$setDataFromList(node, parentId, timeStamp) {
    var p = this.properties;

    if (!timeStamp || timeStamp > this.getTimeStamp()) {
        var tmp;

        if (tmp = $xml.getInnerText(node, "@ExtendedInfo")) {
            p.extendedInfo = tmp;
        }
    }

    if (p.isInitiative) {
        this.callBase("Tridion.ContentManager.InitiativeComponent", "setDataFromList", [node, parentId, timeStamp]);
    } else {
        this.callBase("Tridion.ContentManager.Component", "setDataFromList", [node, parentId, timeStamp]);
    }


};

/* get item icon */
GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedComponent.prototype.getItemIcon = function ExtendedComponent$getItemIcon() {
    var icon = this.callBase(this.defaultBase, "getItemIcon");
    return icon;
};

GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedComponent.prototype.getExtendedInfo = function ExtendedComponent$extendedInfo() {
    var p = this.properties;
    var xmlDoc;
    if (p.extendedInfo === undefined && (xmlDoc = this.getXmlDocument())) {
        //p.extendedInfo = $xml.selectSingleNode(xmlDoc, "/tcm:Page[@ExtendedInfo='true']") ? true : false;
        p.extendedInfo = $xml.selectSingleNode(xmlDoc, "/tcm:Page[@ExtendedInfo='true']") ? true : false;
    }
    return p.extendedInfo;
};


GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedComponent.prototype.getListItemXmlAttributes = function ExtendedComponent$getListItemXmlAttributes(customAttributes) {
    var attribs = {};
    var p = this.properties;

    if (customAttributes) {
        for (var attr in customAttributes) {
            attribs[attr] = customAttributes[attr];
        }
    }
    //This adds my custom column back when the item is updated
    attribs["ExtendedInfo"] = p.extendedInfo;
    if (p.isInitiative) {
        return this.callBase("Tridion.ContentManager.InitiativeComponent", "getListItemXmlAttributes", [attribs]);
    } else {
        return this.callBase("Tridion.ContentManager.Component", "getListItemXmlAttributes", [attribs]);
    }
};
```

**ExtendedPage.js**

```
Type.registerNamespace("GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI");

GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedPage = function ExtendedPage(id) {
    Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedPage");
    // test if initiative (from OME) exists
    var isInitiative = false;
    if (Tridion.OO.implementsInterface(this, "Tridion.OnlineMarketing.UI.InitiativePage")) {
        this.addInterface("Tridion.OnlineMarketing.UI.InitiativePage", [id]);
        isInitiative = true;
    } else {
        this.addInterface("Tridion.ContentManager.Page", [id]);
    }
    var p = this.properties;
    p.isInitiative = isInitiative;
    p.extendedInfo = undefined;

};

GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedPage.prototype.setDataFromList = function ExtendedPage$setDataFromList(node, parentId, timeStamp) {
    var p = this.properties;
    if (!timeStamp || timeStamp > this.getTimeStamp()) {
        var tmp;
        if (tmp = $xml.getInnerText(node, "@ExtendedInfo")) {
            p.extendedInfo = tmp;
        }
    }
    if (p.isInitiative) {        
        this.callBase("Tridion.ContentManager.InitiativePage", "setDataFromList", [node, parentId, timeStamp]);
    } else {        
        this.callBase("Tridion.ContentManager.Page", "setDataFromList", [node, parentId, timeStamp]);
    }


};

/* get item icon */
GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedPage.prototype.getItemIcon = function ExtendedPage$getItemIcon() {
    debugger;
    var icon = this.callBase(this.defaultBase, "getItemIcon");
    return icon;
};

GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedPage.prototype.getExtendedInfo = function ExtendedPage$extendedInfo() {
    var p = this.properties;
    var xmlDoc;
    if (p.extendedInfo === undefined && (xmlDoc = this.getXmlDocument())) {
        p.extendedInfo = $xml.selectSingleNode(xmlDoc, "/tcm:Page[@ExtendedInfo='true']") ? true : false;
    }
    return p.extendedInfo;
};

GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedPage.prototype.getListItemXmlAttributes = function ExtendedPage$getListItemXmlAttributes(customAttributes) {
    var attribs = {};
    var p = this.properties;

    if (customAttributes) {
        for (var attr in customAttributes) {
            attribs[attr] = customAttributes[attr];
        }
    }
    //This adds my custom column back when the item is updated

    p.extendedInfo = this.getPageTemplateTitle();    
    attribs["ExtendedInfo"] = "PT: " + p.extendedInfo;

    if (p.isInitiative) {
        return this.callBase("Tridion.ContentManager.InitiativePage", "getListItemXmlAttributes", [attribs])
    } else {
        return this.callBase("Tridion.ContentManager.Page", "getListItemXmlAttributes", [attribs])
    }


};

/* get page template for the page */
GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedPage.prototype.getPageTemplateTitle = function Page$getPageTemplateTitle() {
    var p = this.properties;
    if (this.getXmlDocument()) {
        p.pageTemplateTitle = $xml.getInnerText(p.xmlDoc, "/tcm:Page/tcm:Data/tcm:PageTemplate/@xlink:title") || null;
    }

    return p.pageTemplateTitle;
};
```

I've a Virtual Directory in IIS under Tridion website called **"DataExtender"** with a folder **"Scripts"** which has **ExtendedComponent.js** and **ExtendedPage.js** and the **DataExtender.config** file.

In System.config (located in WebRoot\Configuration) I've added this:

```
<editor name="DataExtender">
  <installpath>D:\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\DataExtender\</installpath>
  <configuration>DataExtender.config</configuration>
  <vdir>DataExtender</vdir>
</editor>
```

Then I've the c# part which I know is working as I see the column in the GUI with the correct value (but value is lost upon component/page opening).

Anything I'm missing?

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to create a `commandset` in your **DataExtender.config** whose implementation `attribute` is the JS object defined in `ExtendedComponent.js`. The `dependency` element is the name of the resource group that specifies the JS files that needs to be loaded when this extension is clicked on the UI.

```
<commands>
    <cfg:commandset id="Extensions.Commands.ExtendedComponent">
      <cfg:command name="ExtendedComponent" implementation="GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.ExtendedComponent"/>
      <cfg:dependencies>
        <cfg:dependency>GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.Model</cfg:dependency>
      </cfg:dependencies>
    </cfg:commandset>
</commands>
```

Similarly you'd have to create a command for `ExtendedPage.js` as well.

Comment: He's not extending a command, though :)

Comment: Ah, didn't realize he was extending a model. Sorry! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to extend **Tridion.ContentManager.Component** which is a *model* object -- yet you are configuring your extension as an *editor* extension. You should change your configuration to be a model extension instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue earlier and found that namespace mismatch between the assembly and javascript has caused the js files not loaded properly witout any errors in the browser console.

```
[ControlResources("GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI")]
<cfg:group name="GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI.Model">
Type.registerNamespace("GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Where should I put [ControlResources("GUIDataExtender.Extensions.UI")]?